# How clear CodeCombat codecombat sarven desert Hoarding Gold?

Tags: javascript

How clear this stage?

Please help me.

> Line9 : Type error : Can't read protected property : MoveXY

```html
// Collect 25 gold, and then tell Naria the total.
// Use break to stop collecting when totalGold >= 25.

var totalGold = 0;
var coin = 0;

while (true) { 
  coin = this.findNearestItem();
  this.moveXY(this.pos.x,this.pos.y);
  totalGold = totalGold + coin.value;

  if(totalGold >= 25){
      break;   
  }
}

this.moveXY(58,33);
this.say("I Have " + totalGold + "coins");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line:

```
this.moveXY(this.pos.x,this.pos.y);
```

You are commanding your hero to move to its own position.
You want to have the hero move to the coin's position.

PS. While StackOverflow is great, you'll probably find more help over at CodeCombat's forums:

http://discourse.codecombat.com